# IF(Match function returning #N/A when string is expected

Tags: excel

I'm currently doing some data analysis work for reference data from two different sources.

For example from one system, A1 is Samoa, American and the other B1 is American Samoa.

I'm using the following function =IF(Match(A1,B1),"Match","Not")

For all the matching "Match" is coming up as expected.  For all the "Not" matching cells, I am getting the #N/An error.

Can anyone explain to me how to fix this and why it is happening?  Thanks!

Your post has been edited!!!

Comment: Are you missing the quote after not? Also, MATCH isn't used to determine if two strings match eachother like this. MATCH (if I am not mistaken) is used to determine the position of a match within an array. You may want to simply try "IF("A1"="B1", "Match", "Not")"

Comment: woops sorry nope here is my exact code from the spreadsheet

=IF(MATCH(N8,A8),"Match", "Not")

Answer (score 3):

Match returns a number or an error not TRUE/FALSE.

The IF function assumes anything that is >0 to be TRUE. That is why when it matches it works.

Also when comparing two cells MATCH is overkill.

```
=IF(A1=B1,"Match","Not")
```

Match searches a range for a match and returns the relative position of that match.

So to search if A1 is in Column B, we would use:

```
=MATCH(A1,B:B,0)
```

If A1 is not found in column B the MATCH returns an error.  If it is found it would return the relative position in the range, in this case it would equal the row number.

For more information on the MATCH function see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: so what do you recommend for doing a cell by cell comparison?  I could use exact but I would need to remove case sensitivity in that case.

Comment: @stevepark MATCH does not do what you think it does.  In this instance do not use MATCH.  If the MATCH returns an error then the whole function will return that error, not the false of the IF.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was misunderstanding how Match works.  I used what you last referenced and it seems to be working. appreciate the help!

Comment: If that worked, then please finish the paperwork and mark the post as the answer as described in the [Tour].